# How to use foundry cast call when the method returns a struct?

Tags: solidity, foundry, forge, cast

In a deployed contract (in sepolia) there is a method `readTimelock(address,uint256)` that returns a `TimeLock`, which is a struct like the following:

```
   struct TimeLock{
     uint160 amount,
     uint64 time,
     bool withdrawn
    }
```

I would like to make a call to the contract and get that timelock using foundry `cast call`. I'm trying with something like:

```
cast call 0x243B56EDb7BD8B0Aa6fE554A4860405717b8CC4a "readTimeLock(address,uint256)(uint160,uint64,bool)" 0x37aFaa6c1B0cD3c92DE24C09451FD046fA7CbfC3 0 --rpc-url $SEPOLIA_URL
```

The error I get is the following:

```
(code: -32000, message: execution reverted, data: None)
```

Unfortunately, in the documentation nothing is said about function returning structs. Thanks.
https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/cast/cast-call

Other errors I get trying different compositions is simply "Invalid data"

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED.

My apologies, it turns out that the syntax call in the question was actually correct. I misspelled the function `readTimeLock()` which should have been instead of `readTimelock()`.

I guess the lesson here is that when `cast` throws the error:

```
 (code: -32000, message: execution reverted, data: None)
```

it indicates that the method is not part of the code deployed at that contract address, so either a wrong address, a wrong network, or a misspelling of the function.

Anyways, this is the right call:

```
cast call 0x243B56EDb7BD8B0Aa6fE554A4860405717b8CC4a --rpc-url $SEPOLIA_RPC_URL "readTimelock(address,uint256)(uint160,uint64,bool)" 0x37aFaa6c1B0cD3c92DE24C09451FD046fA7CbfC3 0
```

which returns three values corresponding to `(uint160,uint64,bool)`:

```
600
1683570501
false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see an example of working with a struct or custom type here in the [foundry `abi-encode` method](https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/cast/cast-abi-encode).

Example:

```
cast abi-encode "someFunc((string,uint256))" "(myString,1)"
```

For your `TimeLock` example:

```js
struct TimeLock{
    uint160 amount,
    uint64 time,
    bool withdrawn
}
```

```bash
cast call 0x243B56EDb7BD8B0Aa6fE554A4860405717b8CC4a "readTimeLock(address,uint256,(uint160,uint64,bool))" 0x37aFaa6c1B0cD3c92DE24C09451FD046fA7CbfC3 0 "(the_uint160,the_uint64,the_bool)" --rpc-url $SEPOLIA_URL
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, Patrick. However, my issue is not how to call with a struct as input argument, but how to parse (or decode) an output struct. The function from the question returns a struct, and when I try to call the `readTimelock` method I get errors like "Invalid data".

Comment: So are you all set? I'm not sure I follow your current answer. If this is your new question, could you either edit your original question or create a new one and link it here? Happy to help with a newly formatted question or if you edit the current one.

Comment: I am all set, thanks! I will update the answer so that it is less vague